# Ruby 2.1.3 Finding irb file

Tags: ruby

I am beginning Ruby and in the book "Beginning Ruby" it says to set enter c:\ruby\bin\irb and also path to c:\ruby\bin and I should see    irb(main):001:0> in the prompt.
But I get an error that the system can't find specified path. Can any one help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you installed ruby?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Opening interactive ruby by itself does the trick. Thanks